# Webservice not responding in android

Tags: android, web-services, exception

This is the sample code for web services which am trying to implement . I have included all the required jar files to it and try to run the project it is giving me some error [image: like]this  and  this is my [image: logcat]
and my code look like this

```
  private static final String URL = 
            "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";    

        private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
        private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFarenheit";

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

           request.addProperty("Celsius","32");

           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
                new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
               envelope.dotNet=true;
               envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);


            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                SoapPrimitive resultString =(SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                //tv.setHint("Received :" +resultString.toString());
                tv.setText("status" +resultString);
            }
                catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Help me in this. Thanks in advance

```
10-28 11:01:13.501: INFO/AndroidRuntime(369): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-28 11:01:14.452: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(382): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-28 11:01:14.452: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(382): CheckJNI is ON
10-28 11:01:14.992: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(382): --- registering native functions ---
10-28 11:01:16.571: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.option.matrix/.act }
10-28 11:01:17.041: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(382): Shutting down VM
10-28 11:01:17.080: DEBUG/dalvikvm(382): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-28 11:01:17.111: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Start proc com.option.matrix for activity com.option.matrix/.act: pid=389 uid=10035 gids={3003, 1015}
10-28 11:01:17.152: INFO/AndroidRuntime(382): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-28 11:01:18.322: WARN/Resources(389): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f050000}
10-28 11:01:20.121: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Displayed activity com.option.matrix/.act: 3093 ms (total 3093 ms)
10-28 11:01:25.261: DEBUG/dalvikvm(188): GC_EXPLICIT freed 168 objects / 11800 bytes in 95ms
10-28 11:01:30.311: DEBUG/dalvikvm(127): GC_EXPLICIT freed 760 objects / 44080 bytes in 139ms
10-28 11:01:35.270: DEBUG/dalvikvm(266): GC_EXPLICIT freed 46 objects / 2192 bytes in 96ms
10-28 11:01:41.564: DEBUG/SntpClient(67): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-28 11:01:55.622: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(397): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-28 11:01:55.622: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(397): CheckJNI is ON
10-28 11:01:56.090: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(397): --- registering native functions ---
10-28 11:01:57.630: DEBUG/dalvikvm(188): GC_EXPLICIT freed 111 objects / 6024 bytes in 116ms
10-28 11:01:57.760: DEBUG/PackageParser(67): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl12881.tmp
10-28 11:01:57.792: INFO/PackageParser(67): com.option.matrix: compat added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
10-28 11:01:58.090: INFO/PackageManager(67): Removing non-system package:com.option.matrix
10-28 11:01:58.090: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Force stopping package com.option.matrix uid=10035
10-28 11:01:58.151: INFO/Process(67): Sending signal. PID: 389 SIG: 9
10-28 11:01:58.202: INFO/WindowManager(67): WIN DEATH: Window{43fe7498 com.option.matrix/com.option.matrix.act paused=false}
10-28 11:01:58.250: INFO/UsageStats(67): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.option.matrix
10-28 11:01:58.500: WARN/InputManagerService(67): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 389 uid 10035
10-28 11:01:59.031: DEBUG/PackageManager(67): Scanning package com.option.matrix
10-28 11:01:59.040: INFO/PackageManager(67): Package com.option.matrix codePath changed from /data/app/com.option.matrix-2.apk to /data/app/com.option.matrix-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
10-28 11:01:59.050: INFO/PackageManager(67): /data/app/com.option.matrix-1.apk changed; unpacking
10-28 11:01:59.072: DEBUG/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.option.matrix-1.apk' ---
10-28 11:01:59.532: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:01:59.532: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:01:59.551: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:01:59.551: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:01:59.561: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:01:59.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:01:59.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:01:59.590: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:01:59.590: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:01:59.811: INFO/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:01:59.811: INFO/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:01:59.831: INFO/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:01:59.841: INFO/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:01:59.841: INFO/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:01:59.851: INFO/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:01:59.870: INFO/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:01:59.880: INFO/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:01:59.890: INFO/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;'
10-28 11:01:59.911: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:01:59.911: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:01:59.911: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:01:59.921: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:01:59.931: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:01:59.931: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:01:59.931: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:01:59.960: INFO/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;'
10-28 11:01:59.991: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:01:59.991: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:02:00.050: DEBUG/dalvikvm(404): DexOpt: load 141ms, verify 432ms, opt 20ms
10-28 11:02:00.111: DEBUG/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.option.matrix-1.apk' (success) ---
10-28 11:02:00.121: WARN/PackageManager(67): Code path for pkg : com.option.matrix changing from /data/app/com.option.matrix-2.apk to /data/app/com.option.matrix-1.apk
10-28 11:02:00.121: WARN/PackageManager(67): Resource path for pkg : com.option.matrix changing from /data/app/com.option.matrix-2.apk to /data/app/com.option.matrix-1.apk
10-28 11:02:00.121: DEBUG/PackageManager(67):   Activities: com.option.matrix.act
10-28 11:02:00.130: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Force stopping package com.option.matrix uid=10035
10-28 11:02:00.391: INFO/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.option.matrix-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.option.matrix-1.apk@classes.dex
10-28 11:02:00.401: DEBUG/PackageManager(67): New package installed in /data/app/com.option.matrix-1.apk
10-28 11:02:00.731: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Force stopping package com.option.matrix uid=10035
10-28 11:02:00.920: DEBUG/dalvikvm(127): GC_EXPLICIT freed 100 objects / 4248 bytes in 172ms
10-28 11:02:01.071: DEBUG/dalvikvm(67): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6919 objects / 454440 bytes in 219ms
10-28 11:02:01.590: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(67): no available voice recognition services found
10-28 11:02:01.801: DEBUG/dalvikvm(164): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2027 objects / 103008 bytes in 620ms
10-28 11:02:02.031: DEBUG/dalvikvm(67): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3663 objects / 204224 bytes in 175ms
10-28 11:02:02.090: INFO/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.option.matrix-2.apk@classes.dex
10-28 11:02:02.121: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(397): Shutting down VM
10-28 11:02:02.151: DEBUG/dalvikvm(397): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-28 11:02:02.192: INFO/AndroidRuntime(397): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-28 11:02:03.151: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(410): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-28 11:02:03.151: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(410): CheckJNI is ON
10-28 11:02:03.673: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(410): --- registering native functions ---
10-28 11:02:05.451: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.option.matrix/.act }
10-28 11:02:05.642: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(410): Shutting down VM
10-28 11:02:05.710: DEBUG/dalvikvm(410): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-28 11:02:05.751: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Start proc com.option.matrix for activity com.option.matrix/.act: pid=417 uid=10035 gids={3003, 1015}
10-28 11:02:05.822: INFO/AndroidRuntime(410): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-28 11:02:06.551: DEBUG/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 279 objects / 10576 bytes in 500ms
10-28 11:02:06.801: DEBUG/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47 objects / 2040 bytes in 209ms
10-28 11:02:07.291: DEBUG/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2 objects / 64 bytes in 441ms
10-28 11:02:07.611: WARN/Resources(417): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f050000}
10-28 11:02:09.400: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Displayed activity com.option.matrix/.act: 3773 ms (total 3773 ms)
10-28 11:06:41.571: DEBUG/SntpClient(67): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-28 11:11:41.580: DEBUG/SntpClient(67): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-28 11:16:41.583: DEBUG/SntpClient(67): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-28 11:18:40.710: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(425): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-28 11:18:40.756: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(425): CheckJNI is ON
10-28 11:18:44.668: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(425): --- registering native functions ---
10-28 11:18:51.360: DEBUG/dalvikvm(188): GC_EXPLICIT freed 240 objects / 15472 bytes in 3581ms
10-28 11:18:51.531: DEBUG/PackageParser(67): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl12882.tmp
10-28 11:18:51.580: INFO/PackageParser(67): com.option.matrix: compat added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
10-28 11:18:51.911: INFO/PackageManager(67): Removing non-system package:com.option.matrix
10-28 11:18:51.911: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Force stopping package com.option.matrix uid=10035
10-28 11:18:52.031: INFO/Process(67): Sending signal. PID: 417 SIG: 9
10-28 11:18:52.102: INFO/UsageStats(67): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.option.matrix
10-28 11:18:52.121: INFO/WindowManager(67): WIN DEATH: Window{43ff8aa8 com.option.matrix/com.option.matrix.act paused=false}
10-28 11:18:52.587: WARN/InputManagerService(67): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 417 uid 10035
10-28 11:18:53.532: DEBUG/PackageManager(67): Scanning package com.option.matrix
10-28 11:18:53.541: INFO/PackageManager(67): Package com.option.matrix codePath changed from /data/app/com.option.matrix-1.apk to /data/app/com.option.matrix-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
10-28 11:18:53.561: INFO/PackageManager(67): /data/app/com.option.matrix-2.apk changed; unpacking
10-28 11:18:53.591: DEBUG/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.option.matrix-2.apk' ---
10-28 11:18:54.120: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:18:54.120: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:18:54.142: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:18:54.142: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:18:54.151: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:18:54.161: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:18:54.171: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:18:54.191: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:18:54.191: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
10-28 11:18:54.450: INFO/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:18:54.467: INFO/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:18:54.480: INFO/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:18:54.480: INFO/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:18:54.490: INFO/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:18:54.500: INFO/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:18:54.521: INFO/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:18:54.542: INFO/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
10-28 11:18:54.550: INFO/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;'
10-28 11:18:54.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:18:54.571: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:18:54.582: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:18:54.591: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:18:54.591: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:18:54.601: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:18:54.620: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:18:54.630: INFO/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;'
10-28 11:18:54.691: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:18:54.691: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;': multiple definitions
10-28 11:18:54.721: DEBUG/dalvikvm(432): DexOpt: load 176ms, verify 495ms, opt 13ms
10-28 11:18:54.762: DEBUG/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.option.matrix-2.apk' (success) ---
10-28 11:18:54.772: WARN/PackageManager(67): Code path for pkg : com.option.matrix changing from /data/app/com.option.matrix-1.apk to /data/app/com.option.matrix-2.apk
10-28 11:18:54.772: WARN/PackageManager(67): Resource path for pkg : com.option.matrix changing from /data/app/com.option.matrix-1.apk to /data/app/com.option.matrix-2.apk
10-28 11:18:54.791: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Force stopping package com.option.matrix uid=10035
10-28 11:18:54.811: DEBUG/PackageManager(67):   Activities: com.option.matrix.act
10-28 11:18:55.210: DEBUG/dalvikvm(67): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9816 objects / 509592 bytes in 196ms
10-28 11:18:55.430: INFO/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.option.matrix-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.option.matrix-2.apk@classes.dex
10-28 11:18:55.441: DEBUG/PackageManager(67): New package installed in /data/app/com.option.matrix-2.apk
10-28 11:18:55.860: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Force stopping package com.option.matrix uid=10035
10-28 11:18:56.697: DEBUG/dalvikvm(127): GC_EXPLICIT freed 838 objects / 47472 bytes in 808ms
10-28 11:18:57.691: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(67): no available voice recognition services found
10-28 11:18:58.181: DEBUG/dalvikvm(164): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2023 objects / 102904 bytes in 958ms
10-28 11:18:58.401: DEBUG/dalvikvm(67): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5146 objects / 330264 bytes in 179ms
10-28 11:18:58.542: INFO/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.option.matrix-1.apk@classes.dex
10-28 11:18:58.580: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(425): Shutting down VM
10-28 11:18:58.601: DEBUG/dalvikvm(425): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-28 11:18:58.663: INFO/AndroidRuntime(425): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-28 11:18:59.682: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(438): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-28 11:18:59.682: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(438): CheckJNI is ON
10-28 11:19:00.302: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(438): --- registering native functions ---
10-28 11:19:02.140: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.option.matrix/.act }
10-28 11:19:02.342: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(438): Shutting down VM
10-28 11:19:02.430: DEBUG/dalvikvm(438): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-28 11:19:02.481: INFO/AndroidRuntime(438): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-28 11:19:02.836: WARN/ActivityManager(67): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43fdcb68 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
10-28 11:19:02.901: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Start proc com.option.matrix for activity com.option.matrix/.act: pid=445 uid=10035 gids={3003, 1015}
10-28 11:19:04.341: WARN/Resources(445): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f050000}
10-28 11:19:06.131: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Displayed activity com.option.matrix/.act: 3296 ms (total 3296 ms)
10-28 11:19:11.280: DEBUG/dalvikvm(188): GC_EXPLICIT freed 234 objects / 15520 bytes in 95ms
10-28 11:19:16.300: DEBUG/dalvikvm(127): GC_EXPLICIT freed 797 objects / 45736 bytes in 126ms
10-28 11:19:22.000: DEBUG/dalvikvm(266): GC_EXPLICIT freed 88 objects / 4216 bytes in 779ms
```

Thanks for the response and this is my total logcat starting from the code executes

Comment: Please paste the error in instead of including a screenshot.

Comment: Your images are useless. Post a part of ./adb logcat if you want to have the log.

Comment: Did you set the use permission in the AndroidManifest.xml                 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: yes, i have already given the internet permission to manifest file. Still the problem is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your AndroidManifest.xml as well :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Seeing your logcat you need to catch this exception as well :

```
catch(SocketException ex)
           {
             Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
```

Also I have faced similar such problems before,  I would suggest [you refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7860887/841915).

It is a simple code to access web service from localhost..should work for your case too...just you need to change the URL

Comment: thanks . am getting response from the webservice. When am trying to give some print statements in the java code. But the task is not completed

Comment: what is the task ? is it simply converting Celsius into Fahrenheit ?..I suggest if ur not getting the desired output first test the web service and see if it's working fine or not.

Comment: what do u mean testing the web service. Am checking the url . the url is working perfectly fine.

Comment: ok if it is working fine ...then which task is not completed ?

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems like you are including an implementation of XmlPullParser in your project as well, while there is already one in android. If their version is mismatching, it could cause this problem.