# Soap fault while calling webservice using ksoap2 on android

Tags: android, webservice-client, ksoap2

I am consuming a dotnet webservice on android code using ksoap2.I can successfully call the webservice without any parameters but when I tried to call method using a string parameters i am getting this error mentioned below.

```
soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am adding the parameters in this way.

```
request.addProperty("arg0", "username"); 
request.addProperty("arg1", "pass");
```

Errors thrown in this line

```
 SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself.

Instead of

```
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

i used

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: great job. Even I faced this when I started working on ksoap initially. If u are keen on working with .NET (.asmx) webservices in future refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860887/how-to-call-a-local-web-service-from-an-android-mobile-application)