# Android KSoap2 Get Response

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

I am trying to call a Dotnet webservice from android application in which i have a function(ClienLookUp) which requests the webservice with 2 parameter uuid and status, the response is an array consist of 4 parameters uuid,status,msg,QA the uuid is to be the same as in the request but the service is returning me null. I  have created the session from the same uuid before this function call and session is created but if i check the session status with my ClientLookUp function the response is seesion expired and the returned uuid is null.

The webservice is working fine for other platforms i am not getting that what is the issue behind this either my soapobject is not working or the connection is not established successfully. Iam using the Ksoap2 library for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing before. I created a web service is .NET to send 2 parameters namely username and password for user authentication.

You can refer [How to call a local .NET web service from Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860887/how-to-call-a-local-web-service-from-an-android-mobile-application)

Check the answer I  have posted over there. It will give you some idea on how to go about writing the ksoap code.

Hope it helps,

Cheers