# How to connect to web service with android application project using ksoap2?

Tags: java, android, xml, web-services, ksoap2

I got problem on how I connected to web service using ksoap2
my code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FirstScreen extends Activity {

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen);
    tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    Request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope =  new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet =true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

    HttpTransportSE bah = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try
    {
        bah.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
        tv.setText("status: "  + resultString);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

it says Application MyTest (process com.falafel.mytest)) has stopped unexpectedly!! :(

my error:

```
10-10 13:14:06.690: E/dalvikvm(279): Could not find class  'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.falafel.mytest.FirstScreen.onCreate
10-10 13:14:06.690: W/dalvikvm(279): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 501 (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;) in Lcom/falafel/mytest/FirstScreen;
10-10 13:14:06.690: D/dalvikvm(279): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0012
10-10 13:14:06.690: D/dalvikvm(279): VFY: dead code 0x0014-005a in Lcom/falafel/mytest/FirstScreen;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
10-10 13:14:06.870: W/Resources(279): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070000}
10-10 13:14:06.890: D/AndroidRuntime(279): Shutting down VM
10-10 13:14:06.890: W/dalvikvm(279): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.falafel.mytest.FirstScreen.onCreate(FirstScreen.java:32)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-10 13:14:06.920: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 10-10 13:14:11.240: I/Process(279): Sending signal. PID: 279 SIG: 9
```

Any Help would be appriciated, thank you!

Comment: you didn't even try ... "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject" + google ... first result ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done it

Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export > and finally, checkmark your imported KSOAP2 library.

Also, don't consume a webservice on UI thread, consider a service or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ksoap2` in Android can be challenging sometimes. As ThePCWizard rightly suggested it is better to carry out all network related tasks on the background thread using an `AsyncTask`.

You getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` might suggest that the `ksoap.jar` isn't recognized by your Android project.

Assuming you have the latest `ADT version` installed, you need to add the `.jar` file in the `libs` folder of your Android project. After that right click the `.jar` file **-->Build path-->Add to build path**.

Clean your project and try running the application. It should remove the class definition not found error.

I had implemented a similar application quite some time back. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860887/how-to-call-a-local-web-service-from-an-android-mobile-application).

Hope it helps!