# Push Notifications In android and use of asp.net web services

Tags: android, asp.net, json, sql-server-2008, push-notification

I am working on android app.How can I remotly  access asp.net web servises.
I have tried many tutorials Download Ksop jar and use it.... But unable to insert data into data base by using dot net web services in android....Help me..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: g for google.. remember.G comes before S and also before O .. so first Google then SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may Refer here : [How to call a local web service from an Android mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860887/how-to-call-a-local-web-service-from-an-android-mobile-application)

I think its  the same problem 
may help you

You should see this Tutorial also : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap